# centered div pushing float:right div

Tags: html, css

I have this code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pj1zmL6j/

I'm trying to get the loginbox to stay on the same Y as the logo. I've tried different ways with `float` and `display-inline` and other results I've found with google, but when setting `float` or `display:absolute` on the logo, it disappears to the left instead(but the logobox doesn't get pushed down)

Code:

```css
#top {
  width: 100%;
}

#head {
  float: left;
  width: 694px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#user {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div id="head">
    <h1>logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="user">loginbox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI check this updated version https://jsfiddle.net/pj1zmL6j/3/ hopefully this is what you need

Comment: hi thank you for your reply but I am looking to have the loginbox to the furthest right on the screen but at the same hegiht as the logo

Comment: as is understand you need height to be same and on right as it is in your  fiddle code

Comment: yes in the fiddle you sent the login box is below?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

To the `#top` id

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/zpo4gf75/2/

**Edit**

I tried making the Logo stay in the center all the time.

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tksL54g0/2/

Comment: hi, I'm trying to have the head div centered, and then just have the login div furthest right but on the same height as the head div, this seems to keep the logo to the left? thank you for your response

Comment: Updated answer, check if it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of fixed and dynamic widths (percents).

Here is an example of only use percents to achieve your goal: https://jsfiddle.net/v1wvyc1v/

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
}

#head {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}

#user {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

When you have a fixed width, fixed margin and fixed border sizes added you will run into issues. All of these were causing your login box to wrap below.

Comment: hi, I'm trying to have the head div centered, and then just have the login div furthest right but on the same height as the head div, this seems to keep the logo to the left? thank you